# Dúvida sobre consulta com parâmetros usando AngularJS e http request método get

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, http-request

primeiramente, boa tarde. Venho pedir a ajuda de vocês pois já gastei algumas horas procurando uma solução e nada.

Estou tentando limitar o SELECT *  from listafinanceira para o valor definido no campo select dentro do meu formulário (HTML), por exemplo, "SELECT * FROM listafinanceira LIMIT $search"
Fazendo dessa forma:

```
include("../sqlConnection/connection.php");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$search = $data->fRegistro;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM listafinanceira LIMIT $search";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam(1, $search , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

porém está retornando o erro informando que fRegistro não é um objeto.

Ou seja, não estou conseguindo "coletar" o valor do select por meio do valor em JSON, se eu igualar o $search = 10, por exemplo, funciona normalmente.
Não sei se fui claro o suficiente... Estou usando PDO para impossibilitar o SQL Injection através do prepared statements. O http.get dentro do java script para retornar a consulta está assim:

```
$scope.displayData = function()
    {
        $http.get("../sqlFunctions/selectForm.php",
            {'fRegistro':$scope.fRegistro}

            ).then(function(response){
            $scope.entradas = response.data;
        });
    }
```

Já tentei alterar o método get do http request dentro do javascript sem sucesso, desse modo:

```
$scope.displayData = function()
    {
        $http.get("../sqlFunctions/selectForm.php", {
            params: { 
                'registro': $scope.fRegistro
            }
            }).then(function(response){
            $scope.entradas = response.data;
        });
    }
```

no html:

```
<select name="tipo" ng-model="fRegistro" ng-init="fRegistro='10'" ng-class="['uk-select','uk-form-width-small','uk-form-small']">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>50</option>
                    <option>100</option>        
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o método http get, por padrão, não aceita um corpo e o método [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) do angular não recebe um objeto com parâmetros

Envie os parâmetros via url, por exemplo:

```
$http.get(`../sqlFunctions/selectForm.php?registro=${$scope.fRegistro}`}).then( ... );
```

No php você também deve corrigir algumas coisas:

```
include("../sqlConnection/connection.php");

$search = $_GET["fRegistro"]; //Pega os dados passados por get atrvés da superglobal $_GET

$sql = "SELECT * FROM listafinanceira LIMIT :search"; //Use : e não $

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':search', $search , PDO::PARAM_INT); //Passe o nome que deu acima no SQL, no caso ':search'

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Eu tinha encontrado uma solução, mas não foi tão completa quanto a sua. Marquei sua resposta como positiva, obrigado pela colaboração!